# Calendar View of Calroid not working

Tags: android, view, android-calendar

I have taken the sample code of Calroid and implemented the same in my project. Follwing are the code. But I am getting an exception You must supply a layout_width attribute on every case. I have tried it in several ways in my project but still getting same error.

Activity Code

```
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);


            // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            }
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);


            CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
            t.commit();




        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    finish();
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            // Create the interstitial.


         }}
```

XML Code custom_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/cordinationLayout"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include  layout="@layout/app_bar"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am getting the following exception

```
Process: com.eduims.portal, PID: 2511
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eduims.portal/com.eduims.portal.StudentFragmentActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #13: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5049)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #13: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
                at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5948)
                at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6117)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1225)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1062)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:82)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                at com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment.onCreateView(CaldroidFragment.java:1241)
                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:511)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5259)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the  `app_bar` file in your `layout` folder. I think there is missing the `layout_width attribute` there. Set it on             `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or             `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` (depending on which matches better).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and height to the included layout.

```
      <include  
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```